# User-defined methods in Java

Tags: java, methods

Is there a better way to do this? I don't think I have a full grasp on methods. I don't want to do anything complicated, but I feel like there's a lot of redundancy here.

```
public class Main
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double num1 = 5;
        double num2 = 10;
        sum(num1, num2);
        sub(num1 + num2, num1);
        mul(num1, num2);
        div(num1 + num2, (num1 + num2) - num1);
    }
    
    public static void sum(double num1, double num2)
    {
        double sumVal = (num1 + num2);
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sumVal);
    }
    
    public static void sub(double sumVal, double num1)
    {
        double subVal = (sumVal - num1);
        System.out.println("Difference is: " + subVal);
    }
    
    public static void mul(double num1, double num2)
    {
        double mulVal = (num1 * num2);
        System.out.println("Multiplication is: " + mulVal);
    }
    
    public static void div(double sumVal, double subVal)
    {
        double divVal = (sumVal / subVal);
        System.out.println("Division is: " + divVal);
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
Sum is: 15.0
Difference is: 10.0
Multiplication is: 50.0
Division is: 1.5
```

Comment: define better, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Where do you believe there's redundancy?

Comment: "Better" is a subjective term. It really depends what the code is supposed to achieve. Of course: you wouldnt need all these sub methods there. You could just come in and put all the computations and print statements right in your main method. Or well, you could just print `Sum is: 15.0` and so on directly, as all the output for this code can be predicted without running the code. In other words: there is no generic "reviewing" of such simple code, as we dont know anything about the background WHY you wrote it this way; what you wanted to achieve, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First I would remove the println inside the function and make it a double returning function.

Maybe lambdas to define short methods is what you are looking for.
Here we can use [`DoubleBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    DoubleBinaryOperator add = (x, y) -> x + y;
    DoubleBinaryOperator sub = (x, y) -> x - y;
    DoubleBinaryOperator mul = (x, y) -> x * y;
    DoubleBinaryOperator div = (x, y) -> x / y;
    double num1 = 5;
    double num2 = 10;
    System.out.printf("sum %f%nsub %f%nmul %f%ndiv %f%n",
        add.applyAsDouble(num1, num2),
        sub.applyAsDouble(num1 + num2, num1),
        mul.applyAsDouble(num1, num2),
        div.applyAsDouble(num1 + num2, (num1 + num2) - num1));
}
```

Unfortunately `.applyAsDouble` is a bit awkward. `applyAsDouble` should be interpreted as: *apply* two (double) arguments and get the result *as double* value.

Your solution is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double num1 = 5;
    double num2 = 10;
    BiConsumer<Double, Double> add = (a, b) -> System.out.println("Sum is: " + (a + b));
    BiConsumer<Double, Double> sub = (a, b) -> System.out.println("Difference is: " + ((a + b) - a));
    BiConsumer<Double, Double> mul = (a, b) -> System.out.println("Multiplication is: " + (a * b));
    BiConsumer<Double, Double> div = (a, b) -> System.out.println("Division is: " + ((a + b) / ((a + b) - a)));
    Stream.of(add, sub, mul, div).forEach(x -> x.accept(num1, num2));
}
```

you could write it like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    double num1 = 5;
    double num2 = 10;
    double sum=sum(num1,num2);
    double sub=sub(sum,num1);
    double mul=mul(num1,num2);
    double div=div(sum,sum-1);
    System.out.println("sum is: "+sum+"\n Difference is: "+sub+"\nMultiplication is: "+mul+"\nDivision is: "+div);
    sum(num1, num2);
    sub(num1 + num2, num1);
    mul(num1, num2);
    div(num1 + num2, (num1 + num2) - num1);
}

public static double sum(double num1, double num2)
{
    return num1+num2;
}

public static double sub(double sumVal, double num1)
{
    return sumVal-num1;
}

public static double mul(double num1, double num2)
{
    return num1*num2;
}

public static double div(double sumVal, double subVal)
{
    return sumVal/subVal;
}
```

Comment: Hint: dont just throw code at people without any explanations. Also note that the method calls AFTER the printout are useless, as the results aren't printed and are just thrown away. There is no point in invoking a method that doesn't return a value or cause a side effect.